# Cannot Insert header using the before_import override function in django-import-export

Tags: django-import-export

I'm using `django-import-export` to upload csv files through django admin. I have the ability to override the `before_import` function to add functionality before the import. I have a csv file with no headers, and the actual data starts on line one. I need to add a header, or insert a row before my csv file is uploaded, so that it can be read properly.

```
class UpdateResource(resources.ModelResource):
    def before_import(self, dataset, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
        dataset.header = ['sku', 'quantity']

    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        import_id_fields = ('sku',)
```

This code changes the value of the first row of my csv file to `sku,quantity`, but I need to insert one above that value, not replace it. Alternatively, if there is an option to ignore headers and just map the values to my model from left to right or something, that would be great too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My fix was to store the first row as a variable, create the desired header and append the first row to end of file.

```
class UpdateResource(resources.ModelResource):
    def before_import(self, dataset, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
        first_row = dataset.header
        dataset.header = ['sku', 'quantity']
        dataset.append(first_row)
```

Comment: Thanks that works. You can also get rid of the first_row variable altogether and append dataset.header directly